# Groovy: String representing a List to an actual List

Tags: groovy

Is there a way in Groovy to make a list out of a string? i.e. I have a String `"[0,1]"` , and I want to transform it to `[0,1]` (and actual groovy list) in order to manipulate.

The values of the string might be bidimensional ( `"[ [1], [2, 3]]"` ) but it's for sure it will always be a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Eval.me but obviously, take care of evaluating any old strings

```
def a = Eval.me( '[ 1, 2 ]' )
```

An alternative could be:

```
def a = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( '[ 1, 2 ]' )
```

As the two list forms you give in your question are both valid Json :-)

#### PERFORMANCE

Given the following benchmarking code:

```
@Grab('com.googlecode.gbench:gbench:0.4.1-groovy-2.1') // v0.4.1 for Groovy 2.1
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def r = benchmark( measureCpuTime:false ) { 
  'eval' {
    def a = Eval.me( '[ 1, 2 ]' )
    assert a == [ 1, 2 ]
  }
  'json' {
    def a = new JsonSlurper().parseText( '[ 1, 2 ]' )
    assert a == [ 1, 2 ]
  }
}
r.prettyPrint()
```

I get the output:

```
eval  4661121
json     7257
```

So it's much quicker going the json route ;-)

Comment: This actually works but it's veeeeery slow. I need to process a large bulk of data. Any alternative?

Comment: @Dr.Ikarus Added an alternative...  Is it quicker?

Comment: @Dr.Ikarus Tested the speed...  Json is much quicker :-)

Comment: one thing I'd like to add here... if the string is evaluated to a class, then the class could be reused. That would improve things. But of course, if that is not the use case, then the JsonSlurper is much better here